# Postfix not Modifying header Message-Id

Tags: postfix, pcre

I am trying to modify Postfix Message-Ids and I have tried several things but Postfix just ignores the line in header_checks

```
/Message-Id:\s+<(.*?)@.*?>/ REPLACE Message-Id: <$1@mydomain.com>
```

The original header reads:
`message-id=<20200207203547.E769DE0A51@servername.mydomain.com>`

but I want it to read

`message-id=<20200207203547.E769DE0A51@mydomain.com>`

My `master.cf` file:

```
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
  -o header_checks=pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

The `header_checks` file:

```
/Message-Id:\s+<(.*?)@.*?>/ REPLACE Message-Id: <$1@mydomain.com>
```

My `main.cf` file has

```
always_add_missing_headers = yes
```

The logs show emails consistently have postfix generated headers without the rewrite happening.

I am using postfix 3